# Consine similarity using word embeddings & other metadata

Tags: python, scikit-learn, natural-language

I have a use case where i need to find two similar documents. Each document has some (long) description and some metadata. I can go with TF-IDF representation but i want to take advantage of glove embedding (e.g. "woman is playing" and "man is playing" is same).

I have derived **array** of embedded vector for documents (firstly i converted document to padded sequences of same length, then replaced each word with corresponding embedding) & metadata vector

```
 ------------------------------Glove Emb-----------------------------   --metadata---
[[[-1.2555, 0.6999, ..., 0.0000], ..., [2.6958, 0.6999, ..., 0.0120]], 0, 0, 1, 2, 5]
```

How can i calculate consine similarity from it?

**EDIT: I have glove embedded sequences for each document. i.e. vector of embedding. I don't have any idea about calculating cosine similarity from it**

Answer (score 0):

No need to pad all the sequences to the same length. All you have to do to get a reasonable document representation is to average all the individual glove embeddings in your array. If you want to do a little bit better try doing a tf-idf weighted average of those embeddings.